# Why in macOS Firefox can not use `cmd + F` to search text?

Tags: firefox, search

[I can use Command + F to search text in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DeR1.png),  but I can not use this way in macOS Firefox.

my firefox version is: 79.0(64 bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me in `Firefox 79.0 (64-bit)` on `Catalina 10.15.6`

The only difference is the search bar appears at the bottom. [image]